# Override the reduce method

Tags: java, mapreduce, overriding, reduce

I'm a beginner on MapReduce and I have a problem that I don't seem to find the solution. 
At the beginning, the initial problem is that I couldn't call the reducer (which is still the case and I'm trying to find why). So now, after few researches, I'm trying to add an @Override annotation for the reduce method but I can't as I have the following error : "**The method reduce... must override or implement a supertype method**"
I don't know if it's going to fix the main problem but I don't know why I can't override the method as I don't see what the code misses.

You can find the code below :

```
public class RSJReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>  {
        @Override
        public void reduce(Text paramKey, Iterator<Text> paramValue, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature is wrong. It should be:

`reduce(KEYIN key, Iterable<VALUEIN> values, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context)`

So you have `Iterator` instead of `Iterable`.

See the Java Docs [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I checked the doc earlier but didn't see the mistake... Thanks again.